# How to upgrade directly to 12.10 from 10.04?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 10.04

How to upgrade directly to 12.10 (or latest) from 10.04. When i try to upgrade to 10.10, it gets following error.

```
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem
```

I'm just a beginner in Ubuntu. I have already installed win 7 and i don't want to format my computer. I'm hoping for a quick, easily applied solution.

Comment: Do you have access to the internet through Ubuntu? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Try [this](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/upgrade-to-ubuntu-12-04-from-ubuntu-10-04-via-the-terminal/) and do upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 / 13.04 after that.

Comment: @Bilbin How are you trying to upgrade from 10.04 to 12.10? What are you doing, exactly? Please note that upgrading from 10.04 directly to any release other than 10.10 or 12.04 is unsupported and not very likely to work. As ZDroid says, you should upgrade to 12.04 first, then to 12.10. Without more information about whether or not you need to do it some other way, we may close this as a duplicate of [that question](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/upgrade-to-ubuntu-12-04-from-ubuntu-10-04-via-the-terminal/) (but if you edit the question with more info, it'll be considered for reopening).

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, you can only upgrade to the version that directly succeeds the one you have installed (e.g. you can upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04, but not from 10.10 to 11.10).

If the version you have is LTS (10.04 is, so you can do this), you can choose to either upgrade to the next "normal" release (10.10) or to the next LTS release.

The best way to upgrade from 10.04 to 12.10 is upgrading to 12.04 (the LTS release that succeeds 10.04) and then to 12.10.